# Are Static Library Machine Independent?

Tags: c++, static

Well, I am Developing a program in C++ in an Ubuntu 10.04.1 (Intel Core2Quad) LTS, but the releases are running in a Debian 5.0.5 (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU). Some libraries such as crypto++ or mysqlclient have different versions in both OS. So I decided to compile the binary statically with all the libraries statically compiled in the Ubuntu and then upload the completed binary to the Debian.

I am not sure if this method is correct, because the static libs maybe are architecture-dependent and maybe can get in conflict in the Debian Machine. If I want to use the new library version of Ubuntu in the Debian, should I compile them in the Debian?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're architecture dependant. Usually though, library gets compiled to a common architecture on x86 machines, such as i686 which will run fine on both an Intel Xeon and a Intel Core2Quad (But not on e.g. an old Intel Pentium processor)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not machine independent. The only difference is that all libraries are bundled with the executable, so there is no risk for the program to fail on load with a "library not found" message. In summary, it will works for all linux distributions, but it will not work for Windows, for example.

Comment: Of course, but maybe the library bundled has been optimized for different architectures and distributions. So maybe can crash if I compile all the executable in Ubuntu and then be runned in Debian. I usually use .a libraries stored in /usr/lib,/lib so I am not sure about the compilers flags that have been used for those libraries downloaded by apt.

Comment: Check the .deb file for the package that contains that .a file ? Ubuntu .debs are usually i386,i586,i686 .deb files, optimized for the respective architectures.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But choosing the correct packages is up to you. If you want to be sure that your package will work in all architectures, them, as @nos points out, you should choose the i386 flavor of the package. About distro-dependant packages in the field of development, I can't think of an example (this does not mean that it does not exist).